# SyntaxError: Unexpected token

Tags: javascript, if-statement

For some reason, Unexpected token keeps getting returned.  Any thoughts on how to fix it?

```
var sleepCheck = function(numHours);

if (numHours>=8)
{
    return "You're getting plenty of sleep!  Maybe even too much!";
}

else
{
    return "Get some more shut eye!";
}
```

Comment: That error message is the parser doing its level best to tell you something that directly answers the question.

Comment: You should read some JavaScript tutorial before asking such question, buddy. This is too basic, google would have been faster.

Answer (score 3):

Function in javascript have its body delimites by `{` and `}`:

```
var sleepCheck = function(numHours) { // <-- START HERE

    if (numHours>=8)
    {
        return "You're getting plenty of sleep!  Maybe even too much!";
    }
    else
    {
        return "Get some more shut eye!";
    }
}; // <-- END HERE
```

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is just wrong.  Try this instead:

```
var sleepCheck = function(numHours)
{
    if (numHours>=8)
    {
        return "You're getting plenty of sleep!  Maybe even too much!";
    }
    else
    {
        return "Get some more shut eye!";
    }
};
```